# Will Google AdSense punish me for having 100% width banner ads?

Tags: google-adsense

I'm using Google AdSense and I've read that they don't like people changing their Ad code.

I'm using this code:

```
 if ( adWidth <= 625 )
 google_ad_size = ["100", "50"];  /* Banner (468 x 60) */
 else if ( adWidth >= 626 )
 google_ad_size = ["100", "90"];

 document.write (
 '<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;margin-top:45px;width:' 
  + google_ad_size[0] + '%;height:' 
  + google_ad_size[1] + 'px" data-ad-client="' 
  + google_ad_client + '" data-ad-slot="' 
  + google_ad_slot + '"></ins>'
);
```

I've added a margin-top and a width of 100%, now will Google punish me for doing that?

I don't want to end up a few weeks after launch with Google banning my account.

Answer (score 2):

There are some guidelines by Google as to how you can add responsive ad units to your blog. See the following two pages from Adsense help center.

1. [About responsive ad units](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en)
2. [Create a responsive ad unit](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893?hl=en)

According to information given on those pages, you should use CSS Media Queries and not Javascript to set the size of the ad unit based on the screen width.

I think that you are allowed to add a top margin to the code but to be on the safe side, follow this method - wrap the adsense code within another div and specify a margin for it. [This](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en) page contains guidelines on what modifications are allowed.